# User friendly exception error delphi

Tags: delphi, error-handling, message

I have this method where i execute a sql statement and catch a error in a try except statement

```
AdoQuery := TAdoQuery.Create(self);
AdoQuery.connection := AdoConnection;
AdoQuery.SQL.Add(sqlStr);

AdoQuery.Prepared := true;

try
   begin
      AdoQuery.ExecSql;
      AdoQuery.Active := false;
   end;
except on e:eAdoError do
   ShowMessage('Error while creating the table: ' + e.Message);
end;
```

I can catch the error like this and show it to the user but it's showing some useless info for the user. I Would like to show only the `%msg` part of the error, take a look at the pic:

[image]

I tought `e.MEssage` allow me to get only the `%msg` part but it give me the whole thing hardly understoodable by a random user. How do i get only the usefull info in this case

> Table reftabtest.rPCE already exists

Thank you.

Comment: Check out basic string operations such as Pos and Copy ...

Comment: You have the [Pos()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Pos) and [Copy()](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Copy) functions to operate on strings.

Comment: @LURD Isn't this hard coding? How can i be sure there's always %msg  ?

Comment: Well, if the %msg is not there, show the whole message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`Errors`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/Data.Win.ADODB.TADOConnection_Properties) property of the `TADOConnection` object, what you want is the `Description` member of the `Error` object.

In your case:

```
function ParseOBDCError(ErrorDescription : String) : String;

var
  Ps : Integer;
  Pattern : String;

begin
 Pattern := '%msg:';
 Ps := Pos(Pattern, ErrorDescription);
 if Ps > 0 then
  begin
   Result := Copy(ErrorDescription, Ps+Length(Pattern)+1);
   // if you want, you can clean out other parts like < and >
   Result := StringReplace(Result, '<', , '', [rfReplaceAll]); 
   Result := StringReplace(Result, '>', , '', [rfReplaceAll]); 
   Result := Trim(Result);
  end
 else
  Result := ErrorDescription;
end;

...
 AdoQuery := TAdoQuery.Create(self);
 AdoQuery.connection := AdoConnection;
 AdoQuery.SQL.Add(sqlStr);
 AdoQuery.Prepared := true;

 try
  AdoQuery.ExecSql;
  AdoQuery.Active := false;
 except on e : Exception do
   begin
    if AdoConnection.Errors.Count > 0 then
     ShowMessageFmt('Error while creating the table: %s', 
                    [ParseOBDCError(AdoConnection.Errors[0].Description)])
    else
     ShowMessageFmt('something went wrong here: %s', [e.Message]);
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: This looks promising. But something's wrong with my try except statement. Did i make a mistake? It look liks it doesn't go to except but breaks on AdoQuery.Active

Comment: It doesn't break into the code like this but the message shown is the delphi debugger and not my except message grrr It's delphi 2006 btw

Comment: e.Message says incompatible array and string. And when i tried only the first statement it shows the same errors as in my question and not only the %msg part. Also it now shows both statement which is strange. I disabled the notify exception from the debugger but it still shows the message without breaking into the code then it shows my message from except statement. How is this possible

Comment: for e.Message it doesn't work with ShowMEssageFmt. Putting e.Message in ShowMEssage works. But still shows both statement. Looks like debugger doesn't want to let me handle the error or idk. And also still shows the whole error not only the part i'm interested in :(

Comment: Yeah, so it wasn't debugger it was my code. But now the .Description shows the whole error description like Delphi would do it, how can i get the %mdg part? Do i really have to use Pos and copy?

Comment: Thank you this works. I was just searching for a property or something to get the right message as we can do in c# without all that useless sruff for the user. Anyway i'll use this solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That message dialog wasn't shown by your `ShowMessage()` code.

First, the icon is wrong - that's not the `ShowMessage` icon.
Second, the text you added (`'Error while creating the table: '`) to the message is missing.

This means your exception swallower is not catching the exception, because it's not of the `EADOError` class. So what's happening is the application's default exception handler is showing the exception.

---

Before I explain how to fix it, I need to point out that your exception swallower is wrong (your's should not be misnamed an exception handler).

Because you're swallowing the exception: If another method calls yours it will ***incorrectly*** think you method succeeded, and possibly do something it shouldn't. You should never write code that makes an assumption that there isn't a significant call stack leading into your method.

Swallowing to show a message to the user doesn't help, because it hides the error from the rest of the program. Especially since, as you can see: there is already code in one place that tells the user about the error *without* hiding it from the rest of the program. (The problem you have is that you want a friendlier message.)

---

To fix it:

First find out what the actual exception class is, so you're able to catch the correct error.

Now you have a number of options, but the simplest is as follows:

- First log the exception, preferably with call stack. You don't want to be stuck in the situation where the user gets a friendly message but you as developer lose critical information if you need to do some debugging.
- To get the call stack you can consider third-party tools like Mad Except, Exceptional Magic, JCLDebug to name a few.
- Now show the message to the user.
- Finally call `Abort`. This raises an `EAbort` exception which by convention is a "silent exception". It tells the rest of the program that there was an error (so it doesn't do things assuming everything is fine). But by convention, any further exception handlers should **not** show another message to the user. This includes the default handler's dialog in your question.
- If the default handler is *incorrectly* showing `EAbort` messages, then it should be fixed.

Comment: In fact i have an Exit instead of abort but didn't copied into my question. I tried abort it does the same so i guess there's no big different. The exception class i EOleException but it says undeclared indetifier EOleException if i write Except on e:EOleException in my except statement

Comment: There's a ***huge*** difference between `Exit;` and `Abort;`. The first only exits the current routine, but the caller has no idea you had an error and simply carries on processing as if nothing is wrong. The second exits all routines in the call stack until it finds a handler. (Such as the default handler which displayed the dialog in your question.) That default handler can correctly swallow the exception because everything from the entry point (whether button click, menu item or other action) has been abandoned due to the error. You can now safely wait for the next action.

Comment: As for EOleException, that's included in the ComObj unit. You have to use the unit to use the type.

Comment: Ok I see the difference now. And how EOleExcpetion can help me to get the right part of my message? It does exactly the same as i would get simple Exception statement

Comment: @user28470: because that is the whole ADO error. Thats why you need to extract the definition part using my code. The %msg in the error description is specific for the ODBC provider you are using...